# how to use the if statement with radiobuttons

Tags: android

i would like to start a new activity according to the radiobutton that the user choose.this is my non working code(i m using a toast message for now instead of a new activity)

```
public class cafechoice  extends Activity {   

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
public RadioButton rb1;
public RadioButton rb2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.cafechoice);

        final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_red);
        final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_blue);
        rb1.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
        rb2.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);

}
    OnClickListener radio_listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
             if(v == radio_listener)
            {

            if(rb1.isChecked() == true){Toast.makeText(cafechoice.this, 1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            if(rb2.isChecked() == true){Toast.makeText(cafechoice.this, 1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            }
    }
    };

}
```

@rekaszeru this is my logcatview

```
05-02 17:16:28.206: WARN/dalvikvm(678): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-02 17:16:28.216: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kostas.menu.chania/kostas.menu.chania.cafechoice}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2497)
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1848)
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4338)
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     at kostas.menu.chania.cafechoice.onCreate(cafechoice.java:24)
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
05-02 17:16:28.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(678):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rather use a checkedChangeListener:

```
final CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener radio_listener = 
    new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if (!isChecked)
            return;
        if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.radio_red)
            Toast.makeText(cafechoice.this, 1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.radio_blue)
            Toast.makeText(cafechoice.this, 1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

and in your `onCreate` method:

```
rb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(radio_listener);
rb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(radio_listener);
```

Comment: The problem lies here: `if(v == radio_listener)` your answer is regarding semantics, not the problem.

Comment: you were right, i've realized that as well, and updated my answer. Thank you both.

Comment: what do you mean 'forces down`?? what happens? do you get any exception? if so, please share them

Comment: :) well @MByD, than there's a NPE... +1 for pointing that out

Comment: line 24 is   **rb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(radio_listener);**

Comment: your answer was right from the beginning.the only wrong was that i had to use "1" in the toast message....thanks

Comment: This is wrong :(. If your text's resource id is 1, you use it (but it's better to use it with `R.string.myText`), that wasn't a problem. But the real mistake was, that you've never initialized your class-level members: `rb1` and `rb2`. That was the problem that caused FC.

Answer (score 1):

First, if is not a method.

Second, use

```
        if(rb1.isChecked()){Toast.makeText(cafechoice.this, 1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
        if(rb2.isChecked()){Toast.makeText(cafechoice.this, 1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```

Without `if(v == radio_listener)` becaus `v` is not the listener, but the element you pressed on.

**EDIT**

To avoid the NullPointerException, you should remove `final RadioButton` from both button declaration inside the `onCreate` method. They are already declared outside of the method.

Also, remove the `== true`, but this is just semantic.

Comment: I missed that, but you should remove `final RadioButton` from both button declaration inside the onCreate method. They are already declared outside of the method.

Comment: You should update your answer with this scope problem, to vote it (please).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but I think the problem could be the if clause in the listener:

```
if(v == radio_listener)
```

You should use the view given in that function to check if it's your `RadioButton` by using an `equals()` function or something like that.

Hope you can fix that ;)